# Simplify $\tan3x/\tan x$. Answer given is $(2\sin 2x +1)/(2\sin 2x-1)$

Tags: trigonometry

The question is to simplify $\displaystyle \frac{\tan{3x}}{\tan x}$.

The answer given in my book is $\displaystyle \frac{2\sin 2x+1}{2\sin 2x- 1}$

but I am not getting this answer by solving it. Can somebody help me in solving it and get the answer specified?

Comment: That answer can't be right, as you can see by setting $x=\pi/6$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\tan 3x}{\tan x}&= \frac{\sin 3x \cos x}{\cos 3x \sin x}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(\sin 4x +\sin 2x)}{\frac{1}{2}(\sin 4x- \sin 2x)}\\
&= \frac{2\cos 2x+1}{2\cos 2x-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: the hint helped thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan3x=\dfrac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{\tan3x}{\tan x}=\dfrac{3-\tan^2x}{1-3\tan^2x}$$

Use $\tan^2x=\dfrac{1-\cos2x}{1+\cos2x}$ and $\sin^2y=1-\cos^2y$

Comment: I applied this approach and got partially correct answer i.e 2sin2x=1/1-2sin2x
can you please elaborate the hint a little bit.

Comment: @Prattusha, The answer supplied is incorrect. We just need to adapt correct method, the answer will follow

Comment: I got this one thanks a lot!